# Making a query that combines 1 table and data from another associated with it on same line

Tags: mysql

Current:

Table 1

Dbase(table with account information)

-id……

Table 2

Phonenumbers(table with phone numbers associated with accounts.
Id, maindbaseid, phone type, phone number

Current Rusult
Id1,phonetype1,phonenumber1
Id1,phonetype2,phonenumber2
Id1phonetype3,phonenumber3

Wanted result
Id1,phonetype1,phonenumber1,phonetype2,phonenumber2,phonetype3,phonenumber3.

I am trying to export data from our MySQL database based on 2 tables. One is in relation to the other based in the id column and main database id column. The one table is information on an account, and the other is phone number associated with that account. The data I am trying to export needs to be the information from the account table with each phone number associated with that account in rows next to each other I tried an inner join where maindatabaseid and the column maindatabaseid from the second table matched but it only shows the account duplicated as many times that there is a different phone number. Any suggestions would be appreciated, I am a beginner at MySQL so if you could explain things simpler it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most simple relationships. All you need todo is setup a "Foreign Key" relationship, from say the "phone numbers" table to the "accounts table" That way when you query the phone number table, you will then be able to access all the information from the account related to that phone number. (or the other way round)

Please see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html) documentation on Foreign Keys and how to use them, depending on whether you are using a raw sql connection or an ORM would depend on the best approach on performing your query, the documentation link provides information on using the MySQL console.